# Rails Controller - param is missing or the value is empty: booking (Stripe Integration)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I'm trying to complete a Stripe.js integration into my Rails app for an event booking site and I'm getting the error above. I've looked at lots of similar issues on here and none of the solutions seem to work.

Here's my code -

Bookings Controller

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
before_action :booking_params, only: [:create]
before_action :authenticate_user!

def new
    # booking form
    # I need to find the event that we're making a booking on
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    # and because the event "has_many :bookings"
    @booking = @event.bookings.new
    # which person is booking the event?
    @booking.user = current_user
end

def create
    # actually process the booking
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user

    if @booking.save

        # CHARGE THE USER WHO'S BOOKED
        # #{} == puts a variable into a string
        Stripe::Charge.create(amount: @event.price, currency: "gbp",
            card: @booking.stripe_token, description: "Booking number #{@booking.id}")





        flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
        redirect_to event_path(@event)
    else
        flash[:error] = "Payment unsuccessful"
        render "new"
    end
end

private 

def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token)
end
```

end

booking model

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :event
belongs_to :user
```

end

Booking view -

```
    <%= simple_form_for [@event, @booking] do |form| %>

    <span class="payment-errors"></span>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Card Number</span>
      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>CVC</span>
      <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
      <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
    </label>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
  </div>

      <%= form.button :submit %>

<% end %>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>');
  // ...


  // jQuery(function($)  { - changed to the line below
  $(document).on("ready page:load", function () {

  $('#new_order').submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    return false;
  });
});


  var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#new_order');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // token contains id, last4, and card type
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="order[stripe_token]"     />').val(token));
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};


</script>
```

For some reason its not capturing the booking_params. Any advice or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the error stacktrace and _only relevant lines of code_.

Comment: do you permit the booking_params?

Comment: How do I show the error stacktrace?

Comment: What do you mean 'permit'?

Comment: what does the params hash look like that's getting passed to the controller?

Comment: Is that in my development log?

Comment: This is what's showing in my development log - Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aUzSZSSfmtwbKlD9CdGJKYiCIJWnVXv3nbOc1tKFDE6Ebkwy9QSaY3/slmtCAYDY2ll1ItCeQK7u50rEJN6ZGA==", "commit"=>"Create Booking", "event_id"=>"18"}

Comment: so you're not passing in anything related to the booking

Comment: Should I change all the #new_order statements in the javascript to #new_booking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the function `stripeResponseHandler` before the call that submits the form.

E.G.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>');
  var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
    var $form = $('#new_order');

    if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
    // token contains id, last4, and card type
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="order[stripe_token]"     />').val(token));
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
    }
  };

  // jQuery(function($)  { - changed to the line below
  $(document).on("ready page:load", function () {

    $('#new_order').submit(function(event) {
      var $form = $(this);

      // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
      $form.find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);

      Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

      // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Also, change this

```
$form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="order[stripe_token]"     />').val(token));
```

to

```
$form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="booking[stripe_token]"     />').val(token));
```

Alos, give the form an id, like this

```
<%= simple_form_for [@event, @booking], id: "new_order" do |form| %>
```

it should match the ids in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
$form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="order[stripe_token]"     />').val(token));
```

To:

```
$form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="booking[stripe_token]"     />').val(token));
```

And also remove the line:

```
before_action :booking_params, only: [:create]
```

It is not necessary at all.

Comment: That hasn't changed anything, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok, in that case, what parameters are passed to a controller method when your action is called?

Comment: This is what's coming through on my development log -

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aUzSZSSfmtwbKlD9CdGJKYiCIJWnVXv3nbOc1tKFDE6Ebkwy9QSaY3/slmtCAYDY2ll1ItCeQK7u50rEJN6ZGA==", "commit"=>"Create Booking", "event_id"=>"18"}

Comment: You are missing `booking[stripe_token]` in your form, that is a 100%  reason for this issue. It should be posted in a params, but it is not. the line which I have mentioned is not forming the `booking[stripe_token]` correctly. You can try changing the javascript to use `hidden_field_tag 'booking[stripe_token]'`, and try to set the stripe token in javascript instead of adding a field in the javascript, and then check what happens

Comment: Is it because I'm using #new_order rather than #new_booking in the javascript?

Comment: Yes, looks like. What is the id of the form formed here - `<%= simple_form_for [@event, @booking] do |form| %>`? use that form id instead of `new_order` in line:  var $form = $('#new_order'); and in line: `$('#new_order').submit(function(event)`